# TSQL Query to Remove Dates in Multiple Formats from Text Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query, date-format, string-manipulation

I have a table with list of text values that contain dates in any format types.

I need a TSQL query to remove the dates from each row in the table.

The date samples are below. What is the best way to remove these dates?

[image]

Sample table data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably agree with the comments that suggest solving the problem in an external program that has better string comparisons and manipulations, but this looked like a fun little challenge using TSQL.

The following solution is a **brute force, fuzzy matched, non-efficient** attempt to satisfy the question's requirements.

---

```
--Demo set up
--This is your sample data table 
--I added an additional column called TypeOfUpdate that I use
--to document the pattern that matched the update
Declare @StrTable table (TextCol varchar(100),TypeOfUpdate varchar(30))
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('67185019800138111td.2018.06.29.csv.asc.18.07.01_23.05.csv')  --[yyyyMMdd]
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('FX Spots Forwards Summary2_29-Jun-2018.csv')                 --[ddMMMyyyy]
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('QUINTIL_IRS_Open_20180629')                                  --[yyyyMMdd]
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('Share Register_290618.pdf')                                  --[ddMMyy]
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('PositionFileAP10180629.pdf')                                 --[yyMMdd]
insert into @StrTable(TextCol) values('HereItIs21July2018.csv')                                     --no format found

-----------------------

--The solution
--Create a date dimenison table with various columns for
--desired formats
--Adjust the StartDate as needed
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20180101'
    ,@NumberOfYears INT = 1;
DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);

--Load the #DateDimWithFormats temporary table
drop table if exists #DateDimWithFormats
;WITH DateDim
AS (
    SELECT d
    FROM (
        SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
                    )
            FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
            -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
            ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
            ) AS x
        ) AS y
    )
    ,DateDimWithFormats
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,convert(char(8),FORMAT(d, 'yyyyMMdd', 'en-US')) AS [yyyyMMdd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US') AS [yyyy-MM-dd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-US') AS [yyyy/MM/dd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'yyyy.MM.dd', 'en-US') AS [yyyy.MM.dd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'ddMMyy', 'en-US') AS [ddMMyy]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'MMddyyyy', 'en-US') AS [MMddyyyy]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'MMyyyydd', 'en-US') AS [MMyyyydd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'yyMMdd', 'en-US') AS [yyMMdd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'yy.MM.dd', 'en-US') AS [yy.MM.dd]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'en-US') AS [dd-MMM-yyyy]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'dd MMM yyyy', 'en-US') AS [dd MMM yyyy]
        ,FORMAT(d, 'ddMMMyyyy', 'en-US') AS [ddMMMyyyy]
    FROM DateDim
    )
SELECT * into #DateDimWithFormats FROM DateDimWithFormats

SELECT TextCol as TextColBeforeUpdate,TypeOfUpdate
FROM @StrTable

--Repeat the update for each unique format

--[yyyy.MM.dd]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy.MM.dd], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[yyyy.MM.dd]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy.MM.dd], '')

--[dd-MMM-yyyy]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[dd-MMM-yyyy], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[dd-MMM-yyyy]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[dd-MMM-yyyy], '')

--[yyyyMMdd]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[yyyyMMdd], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[yyyyMMdd]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[yyyyMMdd], '')

--[yyyy-MM-dd]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy-MM-dd], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[yyyy-MM-dd]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy-MM-dd], '')

--[yyyy/MM/dd]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy/MM/dd], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[yyyy/MM/dd]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[yyyy/MM/dd], '')

--[ddMMMyyyy]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[ddMMMyyyy], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[ddMMMyyyy]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[ddMMMyyyy], '')

--[ddMMyy]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[ddMMyy], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[ddMMyy]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[ddMMyy], '')

--[yyMMdd]
UPDATE st
SET st.TextCol = replace(TextCol, d.[yyMMdd], '')
    ,st.TypeOfUpdate = '[yyMMdd]'
FROM @StrTable st
CROSS APPLY #DateDimWithFormats d
WHERE st.TextCol <> replace(TextCol, d.[yyMMdd], '')

--Verify the results
SELECT TextCol as TextColAfterUpdate,TypeOfUpdate
FROM @StrTable
```

---

```
| TextColBeforeUpdate                                       | TypeOfUpdate |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|--------------|
| 67185019800138111td.2018.06.29.csv.asc.18.07.01_23.05.csv | NULL         |
| FX Spots Forwards Summary2_29-Jun-2018.csv                | NULL         |
| QUINTIL_IRS_Open_20180629                                 | NULL         |
| Share Register_290618.pdf                                 | NULL         |
| PositionFileAP10180629.pdf                                | NULL         |
| HereItIs21July2018.csv                                    | NULL         |
```

---

```
| TextColAfterUpdate                              | TypeOfUpdate  |
|-------------------------------------------------|---------------|
| 67185019800138111td..csv.asc.18.07.01_23.05.csv | [yyyy.MM.dd]  |
| FX Spots Forwards Summary2_.csv                 | [dd-MMM-yyyy] |
| QUINTIL_IRS_Open_                               | [yyyyMMdd]    |
| Share Register_.pdf                             | [ddMMyy]      |
| PositionFileAP10.pdf                            | [yyMMdd]      |
| HereItIs21July2018.csv                          | NULL          |
```

Comment: Looks good but unfortunately we are still on SQL 2008R2. Upgrading later in year but not soon enough unfortunately. Will look to see how I can use C# and Regex

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) - add your contribution by editing:</sub>*

I would strongly suggest using an external program (that has many more options such as regex for string manipulation) to make this change.  T-SQL has relatively poor string-manipulation facilities.

At the *very* least I would use SSIS with a C# Script task to handle this.

Also, you should be careful to limit matches to actual date values (for instance, if you look for strings containing 6 consecutive digits, then "444400" could be a match - but wouldn't be a valid date in any of the formats you list).

Be aware that there could be legitimate non-date data that might match a seemingly valid date string: "20101010" could be "October 10, 2010", but it might something else as well; similarly, in the first row of your sample data, both "2018.06.29" and "18.07.01" could be dates - for that matter, "18.07.01_23.05" could be a date with a time.